# MySQL does not create socket when launched at boot

Tags: mysql, systemd, sockets

After a reboot, `mysqld` is running, but no socket gets created and you cannot connect to the MySQL server:

```
# mysql
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
# ls /var/run/mysqld/
```

If you restart the MySQL service, then you can connect to the database as expected. The service takes about one minute to restart:

```
# service mysql restart
# ls -l /var/run/mysqld/
total 8.2k
srwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql 0 Jan  8 19:35 mysqld.sock=
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 5 Jan  8 19:35 mysqld.sock.lock
srwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql 0 Jan  8 19:35 mysqlx.sock=
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 5 Jan  8 19:35 mysqlx.sock.lock
# mysql
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 11
Server version: 8.0.31-0ubuntu2 (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2022, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

Logs from `journalctl` show a reboot at 19:24, a startup at 19:27 and then me manually restarting the service at 19:33

```
Jan 08 19:23:58 green systemd[1]: Stopping MySQL Community Server...
Jan 08 19:24:03 green systemd[1]: mysql.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jan 08 19:24:03 green systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Jan 08 19:24:03 green systemd[1]: mysql.service: Consumed 23.311s CPU time.
-- Boot 31bd3ef983b445389647be5c53761256 --
Jan 08 19:27:31 green systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Jan 08 19:33:29 green systemd[1]: mysql.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jan 08 19:33:29 green systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Jan 08 19:33:29 green systemd[1]: mysql.service: Consumed 10.711s CPU time.
Jan 08 19:33:29 green systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Jan 08 19:34:20 green systemd[1]: Started MySQL Community Server.
Jan 08 19:34:30 green systemd[1]: mysql.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jan 08 19:34:30 green systemd[1]: mysql.service: Consumed 6.314s CPU time.
Jan 08 19:34:41 green systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Jan 08 19:35:19 green systemd[1]: Started MySQL Community Server.
```

Here's the output of `systemctl`:

```
# systemctl status mysql
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2023-01-08 19:35:19 EST; 3h 23min ago
    Process: 2588 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 2596 (mysqld)
     Status: "Server is operational"
      Tasks: 59 (limit: 28700)
     Memory: 1.7G
        CPU: 2min 35.515s
     CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
             └─2596 /usr/sbin/mysqld

Jan 08 19:34:41 green systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Jan 08 19:35:19 green systemd[1]: Started MySQL Community Server.
```

How can I get MySQL to start cleanly after a reboot?

Config is Ubuntu 22.10/x86_64/Linux 5.19.0-28. Problem also occurred with 22.04. Upgrading to 22.10 yesterday did not resolve the problem.

Comment: How large are the databases? It *shouldn't* take MySQL a full minute to get going after a reboot unless you're working with thousands of databases, thousands of gigabytes, or one really persistent error ...

Comment: Nothing over 600 MB. Most are 6-10 MB.

Comment: In that case, there should be some specific error messages in `/var/log/mysql/error.log` that points to why the daemon cannot start at boot, and why it takes so long to manually start.

Comment: The daemon does start at boot. `ps` shows it is running. (This is my first sentence in the question.) But no socket is created in `/var/run/mysql`.